# Cross-platform deployment and easy installation

Tags: python, batch-file, cross-platform, py2exe, scientific-computing

**EDIT**

One option I contemplated but don't know enough about is to e.g. for windows write a batch script to:

- Search for a Python installation, download one and install if not present
- Then install the bundled package using `distutils` to also handle dependencies.

It seems like this *could* be a relatively elegant and simple solution, but I'm not sure how to proceed - any ideas?

**Original Question**

**In brief**

What approach would you recommend for the following scenario?

- Linux development environment for creation of technical applications
- Deployment now also to be on Windows and Mac
- Existing code-base in Python
- `wine` won't install windows version of Python
- No windows install CDs available to create virtual windows/mac machines
- Porting to `java` incurs large overhead because of existing code-base
- Clients are not technical users, i.e. providing standard Python packages not sufficient - really requires installable self-contained products

**Background**

I am writing technical and scientific apps under Linux but will need some of them to be deployable on Windows/MacOs machines too.

In the past I have used Python a lot, but I am finding that for non-technical users who aren't happy installing python packages, creating a simple executable (by using e.g. `py2exe`) is difficult as I can't get the windows version of Python to install using `wine`.

While `java` would seem a good choice, if possible I wanted to avoid having to port my existing code from Python, especially as Python also allows writing portable code.

I realize I'm trying to cover a lot of bases here, so any suggestions regarding the most appropriate solutions (even if not perfect) will be appreciated.

Comment: Beauty is that unix and mac support python out of the box. The only thing you have to make sure is you write your code to be cross platform. So its as simple as dumping the project on their machine and finding python on the path, on windows py2exe or pyinstaller are both good choices

Comment: This question should not have been closed. The question regards: 1) Deployment frameworks 2) Development environments, and 3) if there is any prior art regarding the subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got a [project](http://www.nditoolbox.com/) that sounds vaguely similar to what you're trying to do and I've seen some of the same problems since I usually develop on Linux and port to Windows.  It's a Python + wxPython + NumPy + SciPy + matplotlib + assorted other packages, and what I've found to work best is to use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).  PyInstaller does an excellent job of handling third party Python packages and creates an EXE pretty painlessly.

I think if you're using py2exe or PyInstaller it more or less has to be done on Windows since IIRC there are a few Windows libs that have to come along for the ride.  Maybe you could run a Windows EC2 instance?  Depending on how complicated your application is, you might instead be able to make something work with [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/) or [PyPy](http://pypy.org/download.html).

I have tried downloading Python and required packages before for Windows boxes - it worked but it was always a little fragile.  If you can find an installer builder that lets you specify dependencies (e.g. [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/)-not free but works well), I'd try that first as it seems to be a little more robust.

Answer (score 2):

py2exe works pretty well, I guess you just have to setup a Windows box (or VM) to be able to build packages with it.

Comment: I was worried that that might be the only real solution - guess if no one comes up with any alternatives I'll have to go hunt down windows install media. Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts or ideas regarding my edit about using native scripts to install python and then launch the standard `distutils` setups?

Comment: @mutzmatron My humble impression from writing just a script that sets up a `virtualenv` for an existing Python installation is that it's nontrivial.

Comment: @delnan - Non-trivial as in just a little involved, but doable (and likely already done by someone) or more like youd-be-silly-to-try-it?

Comment: Definitely more involved than just using `py2exe` or a similar tool. You'd be silly to try it before giving those tools a good shot. You wouldn't be silly to try it *if* they really don't support your use case well enough (remember, not using windows is not a use case ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using py2exe for the windows side, and then BuildApplet for the mac side. This will allow you to make a simple app you double click for your less savvy users.